# Как отфильтровать вывод команды?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Я пытаюсь получить координаты ярлыка корзины с помощью

```
s2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('trash.png')

print(s2)
```

Вывод:`Box(left=39, top=32, width=53, height=54)`

Но мне нужно получить только координаты в виде (39, 32)

Comment: попробуйте получить как свойство `s2.left`, `s2.top`, или через индекс, если это возможно `s2[0]`, `s2[1]`

Comment: БОЖЕ ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО)))))Я часа 2 ищу решение, пытался писать кучи строк и циклов для фильтрации пробовал кучи способов а решение было таким елементарным....